# Visual studio code : Debugging, the value of miDebuggerPath is invalid

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have to realize a code in C language, but I am blocked at the very beginning by the debugger. I have read several articles on the subject and tried the various solutions proposed, but without success. I have quite simple code at the moment and I would like to use the debugger, but the following error appears:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0o6Q.png)

I have followed the whole installation procedure as explained on their site (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). However I can't solve this problem.

Could someone help me to solve it?

The code of my launch.json is the following:

[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuW8C.png)

Comment: have you checked that gdb is present in PATH? (Command prompt `gdb --version`)

Comment: Why not directly debug with gdb from the command prompt?

Comment: yes I have checked the gdb --version. I'm beginner in visual code, so I don't try to use the command prompt. I'll look into how to use it in the meantime.

Comment: The command prompt work, but I hope it's possible to resolve the problem of the debugging inside visual code studio. It's easier to debug directly inside the application.

Comment: in my case I remote ssh to the wrong machine, they just really look a like, just one has gdb and vice versa, so make sure to double check

Comment: I'm getting this error and I'm not even trying to debug, just pressing the "Run C/C++ File" button.